# TensorFlow.js model converter frozen model unrecognized arguments

Tags: tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I am trying to convert the frozen model to TensorFlowjs model using TensorFlowjs converter but i am getting this "unrecognized arguments"

Tensorflowjs converter version I tried is 0.8.6 and the latest one but getting the same error.

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_frozen_model --output_node_names = "detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections" ./models tfjsmodel
```

error : `TensorFlow.js model converters.: error: unrecognized arguments: detection_classes, num_detections ./models tfjsmodel`

You can find model here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qc4a6AgYp0TM0mXVwWgJFrHuqhcL9zgJ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of the space between the command option `output_node_names` and the argument `"detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections"`

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_frozen_model --output_node_names="detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections" ./models tfjsmodel
```

Comment: Tried, but the error still persist

Comment: Could you please try with only one output name and see `--output_node_names="detection_boxes"`

Comment: Nope, same error